# Require is not undefined in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, robots.txt

1. There is anyway to parse robots.txt via jquery ?
2. What is "require" function I'm found in lib https://github.com/ekalinin/robots.js ?

   ```
   var ut = require('./utils');
   ```

I can not run require in Jquery.How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

> There is anyway to parse robots.txt via jquery ?

You can use its `$.ajax` method (or one of the shorthand variants for it) to read the file, but jQuery has no special features for parsing the data format.

> What is "require" function I'm found in lib

At the top of the page you link to it says *Parser for robots.txt for node.js*. `require` is part of the Node.js [module loading system](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules) which is based on the [common.js spec](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1). There are implementations designed to run in the browser ([RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) being the most famous one) but the library you found may have other Node.js specific dependancies.